# Delete duplicate records according to difference of seconds

Tags: mysql

I have records example:

```
Orden|   date_record
-----|-------------------
2334 | 2017-05-17 05:00:30
2334 | 2017-05-17 05:00:50
2334 | 2017-05-17 05:10:30
3421 | 2017-05-17 07:09:40
```

I need to delete records that have duplicate ids only where the difference in date_record is less than 30 seconds.
Thanks

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: expected output is important - did you only want the 2nd record above deleted, or the first pair, or something else?

Comment: What happen if you have `00:03, 00:15, 00:40` ? there are less than 30 seconds between each time, but if you remove the middle one, then the last one is +30s from the first one. So what is the logic to delete those rows.

Comment: What if there was a record at 5:00:55? And see comments above

Comment: BTW, your table should have a PK other wise make those query much complicated.

Comment: Try normalizing your database!! Define ID as primary key to get rid of duplicate ids

Comment: If there is a record greater than 30 seconds it is not deleted

Comment: Well, this is fun.

Comment: I have this:

SELECT orden,(unix_timestamp(`date_record`) - unix_timestamp(`date_record`)%60) groupTime, count(*) cont 
FROM tbl_register 
GROUP BY orden,groupTime HAVING cont = 2

This shows me grouped 2 registers of equal "orden" and in a lapse of 30 seconds. Now how do I delete one of the 2? Thank you and excuse me if I do not express myself well

Comment: Again you need to explain your logic. Try to explain what your final result should be? And think on border cases, like `00:03, 00:04, 00:05, 00:34, 00:35` What should be the final result and why?

Comment: There are many way we can handle this problem, but we need the specific logic to know which one is the more appropriated. Which row you want to keep, which one delete. The complexity is when you delete one row you may don't need delete the following, that tell me you need some kind of loop or recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

- I create a table for your data `Table1` and include a litle more data.
- I create a temporal table `newTable`

  - include a `row_number`
  - include a field to mark for deletion
- Create a function to debug ***you dont need it***
- Create a function `process_time` to check for deletion

  - Create a cursor to loop for the table and mark each row when second diff 
    is `< 30`
  - If a row is already marked `<> 0` doesn't count for the next row calculations
- The final step is delete from original table using the `newTable` marked rows

[**SQL DEMO**](http://rextester.com/NNW13914)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE process_time()
BEGIN    
    DECLARE int_id INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE int_prev_id INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE dtt_date datetime;    
    DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;        

    DECLARE newTable_cursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT `ID`, `date_record` 
        FROM newTable 
        ORDER BY `ID`, `date_record`;

    -- declare NOT FOUND handler
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

    OPEN newTable_cursor;    

    get_dates: LOOP
         FETCH newTable_cursor INTO int_id, dtt_date;

         IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
             LEAVE get_dates;
         END IF;

         IF int_prev_id = int_id THEN
             SELECT @dd := TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,  MAX(`date_record`), dtt_date) as d -- MAX(`date_record`)
             FROM newTable
             WHERE `ID` = int_id
               AND `date_record` < dtt_date
               AND delete_mark = 0;     
         ELSE 
             SET int_prev_id := int_id;
             SET @dd := null;
         END IF;                           

         IF @dd < 30 THEN         
             UPDATE newTable
             SET `delete_mark` = @dd
             WHERE `ID` = int_id
               and `date_record` = dtt_date; 
         END IF;

    END LOOP get_dates;    

    CLOSE newTable_cursor;        
END;
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]